# Maui .Net 8 Button Click Animation Missing

Tags: c#, android, maui

Why does the button click animation not work in .Net8 for Maui, but does work in .Net7?

Using the default project for both, only in .Net7 can I see the little fade animation when I press the button.

Was there a change in .Net 8 that I have adjust to get that animation back? I would like this feedback to the user.

I tried updating to .Net8 rc1 but the issue still exists.

Comment: Probably a bug did you check Maui's Github?

Comment: @FreakyAli I did but I couldn't find anything related to it, which I found strange as it's quite an obvious change in behaviour.

Answer (score 1):

You can report this as an new issue on the repo. I created  new .net 7 and .net 8 project to test. And I found that the value of the button's background on the android has been changed.

In the .net 7, the button's android platform view's background value is an instance of the `RippleDrawable Class`. And In the .net 8, it's an instance of the `BorderDrawable Class`. This should be the cause of losing button clicked Animation.

You can try to check the result in the Page's `OnHandlerChanged method` above when you debug the project.

In addtion, I also try to [custom a background RippleDrawable](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/1184992/how-to-use-android-xml-layouts-and-other-xml-resou) for the android, but it didn't change any thing.

Comment: Thanks for this information, I have done what you suggested and raised an issue on the repo. For anyone else experiencing this issue here is the link https://github.com/dotnet/maui/issues/17642